# Approximating summations via integrals

Tags: integration, summation, asymptotics, riemann-integration

I am currently taking an algorithms course, which explains how summations can be bounded by integrals.

The rule for this is 
$$\int_{m}^{n+1} f(x) dx \leq \sum_{k=m}^{n}f(k) \leq \int_{m-1}^{n} f(x) dx.$$

It then runs through an example, where it bounds the summation from below
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k} \geq \int_{1}^{n+1} \frac{dx}{x} = ln(n+1)
$$ 
and from above
$$
\sum_{k=2}^{n} \frac{1}{k} \leq \int_{1}^{n} \frac{dx}{x} = ln(n)
$$ 
after which a $1$ is added for starting the summation from $k=2$.

Here is where my confusion lies however; what was the need to start the summation from $k=2$ and why couldn't we just start it from $1$ like when bounding from below.

Comment: You clearly forgot some assumption concerning $f$. Your first pair of inequalities cannot possibly hold without restrictions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\int_0^{1} \frac 1 x dx$ does not exist so you consider $\int_k^{k+1} \frac 1 x dx$ for $k=1,2,3..$ and and add them to derive those inequalities.

Note that $\int_k^{k+1} \frac 1 x dx >\frac 1 {k+1}$ and $\int_k^{k+1} \frac 1 x dx <\frac 1 k$ for each $k \in \mathbb N$.